# No search results for new records

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, crawling, crawl

I added new records, and did a full crawl to the site, I see that the crawl was successful but when I search the site for the new records I do not see the results. I get "No results found".

its sharepoint 2010

what could it be?

Comment: Does the crawl account have access to the list?  Have you looked at the crawl log to verify the list is being crawled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is only this record unsearchable or all records unsearchable?

Here is a checklist:

1.If it is an item in the list, go to the List settings>Advance settings to check whether the result is allowed to appear in the search results:
[image]

2.Check your permission in this list.

3.Check if this site is included in your content source.

4.Check if you have done any settings in the result source.

5.Have you set any crawl rules?

In addition,have you configured the search center?